# What is the use of Take method ? Flutter & dart

Tags: flutter, dart, take

**take**-->What role does it play (flutter and Dart)

```
class Ticker {
  Stream<int> tick({int ticks}) => Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (x) {
        return ticks - x - 1;
      }).take(ticks);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So simply, it just takes items as count of you pass(ticks parameter) from a stream.

```
// This stream is responsible to do a task for each second 
Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (x) {
    return ticks - x - 1;
})

// With take, stream does it's job only `ticks` times
Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (x) {
    return ticks - x - 1;
}).take(ticks);
```